# How do I avoid the "Subquery returned more than 1 value" report?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I wrote the following script:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Temp
create table #Temp
(
        [KeyName] [nvarchar](max),
        [CertName] [nvarchar](max),
)
Go


INSERT INTO #Temp
EXEC fetch_data

GO

IF(Select #Temp.KeyName From #Temp) = 'SSN_Key_01' AND (Select CertName From 
#Temp) = 'PasswordManager001'
EXEC decrypt_1

Else

IF(Select KeyName From #Temp) = 'SSN_Key_02' AND (Select CertName From #Temp) 
= 'PasswordManager002'
EXEC decrypt_2

Else

IF(Select KeyName From #Temp) = 'SSN_Key_03' AND (Select CertName From #Temp) 
= 'PasswordManager003'
EXEC decrypt_3

GO
```

and keep on getting the error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I simply try to do a little comparison on my returned values and execute them based on the three conditions visible on the script.

Why do I keep getting the report?

Comment: Because the select return more than 1 row , mybe you want to use `IF EXISTS`

Comment: run the fetch_data stored procedure and look at what it returns.  Or, run those subqueries independently and view the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
IF exists (Select #Temp.KeyName From #Temp where KeyName = 'SSN_Key_01' )
begin
if exists (Select CertName From 
#Temp where CertName  = 'PasswordManager001')
EXEC decrypt_1
end
Else

IF exists(Select KeyName From #Temp where KeyName  = 'SSN_Key_02')
begin
if exists (Select CertName From #Temp where CertName  
= 'PasswordManager002')

EXEC decrypt_2
end

Else

IF exists (Select KeyName From #Temp where KeyName  = 'SSN_Key_03')
begin
if exists (Select CertName From #Temp where CertName 
= 'PasswordManager003')
EXEC decrypt_3

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are more than one `CertName` in your `#Temp` table and / or more than one `KeyName`.

If there is one value repeated more than once, you can solve this with a `distinct`

```
IF(Select distinct KeyName From #Temp) ...
```

If you have multiple different values, you can probably solve it with

```
IF (Select count(*) From #Temp where KeyName = 'SSN_Key_01') > 0 ...
```